Unity WebGL Wasm Files return 500 through Nginx on Cloud Run
Our website is hosted with Nginx through a docker container in Cloud Run.
We are trying to add a WebGL built game (created through Unity) onto our website.
Unfortunately, it seems that the wasm file in the Build folder is returning 500 for some reason.
I have tried running the Nginx server locally and it returns 200 with the wasm file.
I have also tried a few change to the Nginx configrutation file, but it didn't do anything.
I suspect the issue is how Cloud Run is serving the file.
